# Slider like bang-olufsen.com/en

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slider

First of all, take a look at this link 
http://www.bang-olufsen.com/en

Can anyone suggest me, what jQuery plugin to create that Image Slider.

As you can see, the Text Caption is inside the black box, 
but the black box doesn't move when the slide is moving.

Can anyone suggest me, what jQuery plugin to create that Image Slider.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of sliders out there. iDangerous has a bunch of nice sliders. Sometimes these are custom and out of the box is going to be achieved.

Take a look here: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Comment: Yes, I know. Many slider out there. But the one with masking text that I searched.